# Python quits silently upon importing tensorflow, no error/logs

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip, conda

I currently have a problem with tensorflow that I've been stuck with for almost 2 weeks now.

No matter what Python script I run, every time tensor flow is imported
`import tensorflow`
Python just quits with no error, no logs, nothing.
It just silently quits similar to when `exit()` is called,
any code that was supposed to execute after `import tensorflow` simply doesn't run.

I've tried both conda and pip, created an virtual environment and installed tensorflow, I tried without virtual environment too
(which generally isn't recommended but I did just to see if it would make a difference).

I've tried every Python version available that works with Tensorflow 2.
I've tried both command prompt and powershell, inside Visual Studio and outside in the file explorer.

I've tried CPU and GPU, installed, removed, re-installed Cuda and everything, including my Nvidia drivers and everything else required to run tensorflow on GPU, also with every Python version, I've tried nearly every Tensorflow 2 version.
I've even tried forcing the GPU/CPU before Tensorflow gets imported.
Even the basic/barebones CPU version simply won't run.

The worst part is that this issue not only happens on my computer that I use at work but it also happens on my personal computer at home, I barely have to do anything as this problem reproduces itself.

I at first thought it had to do with my project but I quickly figured that even just writing a brand new, fresh and empty script with a brand new, fresh and empty virtual env solves nothing (even without virtual env).
Even a clean re-install of Python and Conda did nothing.

I am clueless at this point, I haven't been able to find any solutions on the internet
I depend on tensorflow and this problem is stopping me right in my tracks and prevents me from even testing or doing basic tutorials.

For those who need to know, here is how you could reproduce the issue yourself.

1. Install Python 3.8 or Conda.
2. (Optional but recommended) Create an virtual environment in the path/directory of choice
   with no other package installed than the latest version of Tensorflow 2.
3. Write a simple script with the following Python code.

```py
print('This prints')
import tensorflow
print('This will never print')
```

4. Activate Python/Conda environment.
5. Do `python MyScript.py` in the command prompt.
6. The script should now run but stop after importing tensorflow, the second print statement should never print.

SPECS INFO: I use Windows 10 on all computers, all have Intel CPUs (Both i7).
One of them a Nvidia GTX 1050 the other PC has a Nvidia TITAN Black.

I will try to add more information soon when I have some time.
I don't know if this issue is reproducable for everyone but I've had the same issue on multiple computers with slightly different specs so far even with a clean Python install and environment.

UPDATE: This issue has somehow resolved itself after a recent Tensorflow update, it now functions just as expected.
I still haven't found what caused the problem but it's fixed now, thank you to those who tried to help me out earlier.

Comment: `try: import tensorflow except: print(Exception.with_traceback())` might help shed some light (you'll adjust the newlines and indentation, I'm sure)?

Comment: Nothing has printed in the output or during debugging.
Python once again just quits silently.

Comment: What versions are you using for tensorflow and python?
And are you able to import other libraries successfully? (builtins, pandas, numpy, etc)

Comment: I've tried almost every single version of Tensorflow 2 and Python. I am currently on Python version 3.8 and using the newest Tensorflow 2 compatible with 3.8 since older versions didn't fix anything. 
All other libraries import without any issues, if I put them before `import tensorflow` they just import and load, but as soon as Python reaches that one line that has
`import tensorflow` on it, it simply quits silently.

Comment: What processor do you have?, tensorflow 2.x and later versions of 1.x don't support AMD processors. so may be this is the problem.

Comment: Also you can try installing through docker image which gets you up and running almost directly, which should solve any environment related issues.

Comment: Also keep an eye on `/var/log/syslog`, maybe some error message will show up there. I don't remember exactly, but I think I got some wrong instruction exception when I was running something like tensorflow on unsupported CPU.

Comment: I use a intel CPU on all computers I use Tensorflow on.
As for the docker thing, I shall give that a try to see if that works
(I hope I don't have to change too much code in my projects folder because I want to keep my projects as portable as possible, I make sure I got the same envs and libraries on every PC I work on).

Comment: Alright, so I have tried installing Docker at home.
The problem here is though that Docker is giving me all sorts of problems right now that I have to resolve one by one.and I can't use Docker at work since I'm not an administrator and have to ask permission + explain why I need it every time I want to make changes to the computer.

Using Conda or Pip makes it way easier to install Tensorflow and run it immediately.
I don't mind if I can only run it on the CPU but it just doesn't import for some reason and I can't figure out why still.

Comment: not much information at this link but it suggests that it may be linked to module installation order  https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9384

Comment: This has become a lengthy comment section. It would be better to edit the question with updates, rather than commenting in response. The question still lacks essential information for reproducing. Namely, provide a `conda env export > environment.yaml` for one of your environments that doesn't work - we need to see versions. Also, show exactly how you activate the environment and run a test script. Finally, include a `import sys; print(sys.path)` result, to show where packages are being loaded from - we must rule out non-Conda `site-packages` leaking in.

Comment: Assuming Linux, try running python under `strace`.

Comment: Does this happen when you try from repl?

Comment: Hi! @Acorpze! Could you confirm your Tensorflow version and  platform (whether macos/windows/raspberry pi etc?) , I could not replicate this issue in TF 2.6 colab. Thanks!